# jQuery: small label font size, if the field is not empty

Tags: html, jquery, css, input

I have a code that places a label in a field and reduces its font if we focus in this field. It works perfectly.

But sometimes the value of the field may not be empty immediately when the page loads. In such cases, the label of the field runs over the value.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('input').focus(function () {
            $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
        });

        $('input').blur(function () {
            var inputValue = $(this).val();
            if (inputValue == '') {
                $(this).parents('.form-row').removeClass('focused');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

```css
.form-row {
    position: relative;
}

.form-row input {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 300ms;
    padding: 12px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.form-row label {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 1.7 !important;
    transition: font-size 250ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out,
        -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
    z-index: 10;
}

.focused.form-row label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row">
    <label for="empty">EMPTY</label>
    <input id="empty" placeholder value />
</p>

<p class="form-row">
    <label for="not_empty">NOT EMPTY</label>
    <input id="not_empty" placeholder="" value="John" />
</p>
```

I tried to make a check, but for some reason it does not work in my case.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var inputValue = $('input').val();
    if (inputValue.trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
    }
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var inputValue = $('input').val();
    if (inputValue != 0) {
        $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
    }
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input').on('load', function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        if (inputValue != '') {
            $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

I will be grateful for any help.

p.s. apologize for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load, loop through all inputs to add the `focussed` class on no empty ones.

Note: `jQuery(function($)` is the equivalent of `$(document).ready()` and `window.onload = function () {`... You only need one.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // Checking all values on load
  $("input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
    }
  })

  // Event handlers
  $('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).parents('.form-row').addClass('focused');
  });

  $('input').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).parents('.form-row').removeClass('focused');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-row {
  position: relative;
}

.form-row input {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 300ms;
  padding: 12px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.form-row label {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 1.7 !important;
  transition: font-size 250ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
  z-index: 10;
}

.focused.form-row label {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row">
  <label for="empty">EMPTY</label>
  <input id="empty" placeholder value />
</p>

<p class="form-row">
  <label for="not_empty">NOT EMPTY</label>
  <input id="not_empty" placeholder="" value="John" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my soultion ony with CSS without any javascript code by using the required attribute on the input field.

```css
.form-row {
    position: relative;
}

.form-row input {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 300ms;
    padding: 12px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.form-row label {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 1.7 !important;
    transition: font-size 250ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-out, font-size 250ms ease-out,
        -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out;
    z-index: 10;
}

input:focus + label,
input:valid + label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<p class="form-row">
    <input type="text" id="empty" required />
    <label for="empty">EMPTY</label>
</p>
<p class="form-row">
    <input type="text" id="empty" value="John" required />
    <label for="empty">NOT EMPTY</label>
</p>
```

Comment: This is a wonderful solution! It's a pity can't mark 2 answers as solving the problem)